# Strontium-89 vs strontium-90

Tags: isotope, radioactivity, medicinal-chemistry

Why is radioactive strontium-89 is considered medically useful for bones (along with other benefits) whereas strontium-90 (also being radioactive) is harmful for human body?

How does the addition of one atomic mass has adverse effects on human body?

Comment: "Medically useful" is an awfully vague term. A scalpel is medically useful, come to think of it. A scalpel can kill, too.

Comment: Strontium 89 (or 90) have zero benefit for human bones or other tissue. Sr-89 is used to treat (=destroy) bone metastasis. Normal, non-radioactive strontium is used for treating osteoporosis.

Answer (score 7):

The half-life of $\ce{^{89}Sr}$ is 50 days compared to a half-life of 29 years for $\ce{^{90}Sr}$. So a large enough dose of $\ce{^{90}Sr}$ to be useful would leave the patient radioactive for the rest of his/her life.

---

Edited for use of $\ce{^{89}Sr}$. In a comment Karl pointed out that the isotope is used to treat bone cancer.

Comment: Not so much detectable, mind you. To treat cancer you want to hit it with a nice big dose of radiation in a short period of time to beat it down.

Comment: The physical half-life of Sr-90 is indeed 28.79 years; however, the biological half-time of strontium is shorter. In particular, the removal half-time of strontium from exchangeable bone volume is about 80 d. After ingestion of Sr-90, about half of the resulting total effective dose occurs within the first 4 years after intake.

Answer (score 0):

The specific radioactive properties of an isotope are *very* different even from other isotopes of the same element. The *chemical* properties will be very similar.

The issue for using isotopes for medical purposes is that you need a combination of specific chemical properties *and* the right radioactive behaviour. So one strontium isotope will not be a remote substitute for another.

Answer (score 0):

Both isotopes decay by beta emission, but strontium 90 has a decay energy of 0.546 MeV, while strontium 89 has a decay energy of 1.463 MeV. (CRC Handbook)

The range of the electron from Sr 90 is better suited to putting a strontium atom in the middle of a tumor without irradiating too much of the surrounding flesh.[image]

https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=range+of+beta+particles&fr=yhs-Lkry-SF01&hspart=Lkry&hsimp=yhs-SF01&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alpharubicon.com%2Fbasicnbc%2Fimages%2Farticle16radiological7104.gif#id=1&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alpharubicon.com%2Fbasicnbc%2Fimages%2Farticle16radiological7104.gif&action=click